# Update multiple fields in a single PUT request

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a `Client` table in `Oracle` with the following fields and their values,

```
+----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------+----------+
|client_id |  client_name |         url          |  connection_pool | username  | password |
+----------+--------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------+----------+
|  test    |   clientDb   | http://clienturl.com |       QA_DB      |  user     |  admin   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have created a `PUT` request in my `Java` application which updates the fields.

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Boolean updateClient(@PathParam("id") String id, Client client) throws DaoException {
    this.setupController();
    return controller.updateClientDetails(id, client);
}
```

**ClientsController:**

```
public Boolean updateClientDetails(String id, Client client) throws DaoException {
    Client dbClient = clientDao.getClient(id)); //returns client present in table on basis of client_id
    if (!client.getName().equals(dbClient.getName())) {
        return clientDao.updateClientName(id, client.getName());
    }
    if (!client.getUrl().equals(dbClient.getUrl())) {
        return clientDao.updateClientUrl(id, client.getUrl());
    }
    else {
        LOGGER.info("Unable to update client {}", id);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**ClientDao:** I am updating the `client_name` and `url` separately as below:

```
public Boolean updateClientName(String id, String name) throws DaoException {
    final String sql = "UPDATE client SET client_name = ? WHERE client_id = ?";
    LOGGER.debug(SQL_STRING.toLogback(sql), name, id);
    try (final Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            final PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        statement.setString(1, name);
        statement.setString(2, id);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOGGER.debug("Exception while updating client {} ", id, ex);
        throw new DaoException(ex);
    }
}

//updateClientUrl(String id, String url) method - similar logic as above for updating url value
```

While sending the `PUT` request, it updates the fields *one at a time* i.e., if I change/update more than one value in the `Client` object in the request body, it updates one field in the first request. For the second attribute to be updated, I need to send the request again.

I am wondering is there a way to **update more than one value in a single request** rather than sending more than 1 request and having multiple update methods for every field?

The solution may be simple but it's not clicking me! Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update one or more fields at a time.
For that you have to build your query based on your condition on what you want to change which part/column. So this part of yours:

```
final String sql = "UPDATE client SET client_name = ? ";
```

needs change. You have to build your `sql` query like this(say, your have have client object and its field--):

```
String sql = "UPDATE client SET client_name = ?";
if(client.getUrl()!=null && !client.getUrl().isEmpty())
  sql+=", set url=?";
// similar for other fields you want to update
at last, concate your condition:
sql+=" WHERE client_id = ?";
```

Now, you have to provide those fields which you have set dynamically to your query to update:

```
statement.setString(1, name);
if(client.getUrl()!=null && !client.getUrl().isEmpty())
{
  statement.setString(2, client.getUrl());
  statement.setString(3, id);
}
else
    statement.setString(2, id);
```

For indexing in query position, it is better using an `indexVariable` to keep track of its value automatically on condition.
Please buzz if this does not serve your question.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I missed the part that I could set the fields in the same query rather than having separate ones.